# Getting error while using webhdfs to create directory

Tags: webhdfs

I am getting below error while running below Rest call:

curl -i -X PUT "http://myhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/tempdir?op=MKDIRS"

*"RemoteException":{"exception":"AccessControlException","javaClassName":"org.apache.hadoop.security.AccessControlException","message":"Permission denied: user=dr.who, access=WRITE, inode=\"/tempdir\":root:supergroup:drwxr-xr-x"}}*

Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I added &user.name=root to my url like below and it worked for me.

curl -i -X PUT "http://myhost:50070/webhdfs/v1/tempdir?op=MKDIRS&user.name=root"

Closing the thread.